# iOS: Threading issue when calling setNeedDisplay inside callback function

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, audio

**Here is the context:**
 I've been developing an audio-related app for a while now and I sort of hit a wall and not sure what to do next.

I've recently implemented in the app a custom class that plots a FFT display of the audio output. This class is a subclass of UIView meaning that every time I need to plot a new FFT update I need to call `setNeedDisplay` on my instance of the class with new sample values.

As I need to plot a new FFT for every frame (frame ~= 1024 samples), it means that the display function of my FFT gets called a lot (1024 / SampleRate ~= 0.02321 second). As for the sample calculation, it is done 44'100 / sec. I am not really experienced with managing threading in iOS so I read a little bit about it and here is how I have done it.

**How it has been done:** I have a subclass of NSObject "AudioEngine.h" that is taking care of all the DSP processing in my app and this is where I am setting my FFT display. All the sample values are calculated and assigned to my FFT subclass inside a `dispatch_get_global_queue` block as the values need to constantly be updated in the background. The `setneedDisplay` method is called once the samples index has reached the maximum frame number, and this is done inside a `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue)` block

In "AudioEngine.m"

```
for (k = 0; k < nchnls; k++) {

            buffer = (SInt32 *) ioData->mBuffers[k].mData;

            if (cdata->shouldMute == false) {

                buffer[frame] = (SInt32) lrintf(spout[nsmps++]*coef) ;

                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
                        @autoreleasepool {

                            // FFT display init here as a singleton
                            SpectralView *specView = [SpectralView sharedInstance];

                            //Here is created a pointer to the "samples" property of my subclass
                            Float32 *specSamps = [specView samples];

                            //set the number of frames the FFT should take
                            [specView setInNumberFrames:inNumberFrames];

                            //scaling sample values
                            specSamps[frame] = (buffer[frame] * (1./coef) * 0.5);
                        }
                    });

            } else {
             // If output is muted
                buffer[frame] = 0;
            }
        }

        //once the number of samples has reached ksmps (vector size) we update the FFT
        if (nsmps == ksmps*nchnls){
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    SpectralView *specView = [SpectralView sharedInstance];
                    [specView prepareToDraw];
                    [specView setNeedsDisplay];
                });
```

**What my issue is:**

1. I get various threading issues, especially on the main thread such as `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0xf00000c)`, sometimes on the app launch as the viewDidLoad is being called, but also whenever I try to interact with any UI object.
2. The UI responsiveness becomes insanely slow, even on the FFT display.

**What I think the problem is:** It is definitely related to a threading issue as you may know but I am really unexperienced with this topic. I thought about maybe force any UI display update on the main thread in order to solve the issues I have but again; I am not even sure how to do that properly.

Any input/insight would be a huge help.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What thread is the above code running on?

_I thought about maybe force any UI display update on the main thread in order to solve the issues I have but again; I am not even sure how to do that properly._

All UIKit calls must occur on the main thread, and you can do so from another thread by calling `dispatch_async()` with the main queue, as you are doing in the last lines of code, above. You should not make UIKit calls from the `dispatch_get_global_queue()` queue (that's for concurrent execution).

Comment: have you made sure your `SpectralView` singleton is thread safe? The `sharedInstance` method should be using `dispatch_once`, and make sure that the methods you are calling on it from the background aren't in any way updating the UI. You should also make sure that any properties on it that are getting called from multiple threads are getting serialised correctly.

Comment: @originaluser2 really good point. I haven't even noticed that I wasn't using `dispatch_once`on my View.

Answer (score 2):

As written, your `SpectralView*` needs to be fully thread safe.

Your `for()` loop is first shoving frame/sample processing off to the high priority concurrent queue.   Since this is asynchronous, it is going to return immediately, at which point your code is going to enqueue a request on the main threat to update the spectral view's display.

This pretty much guarantees that the spectral view is going to have to be updating the display simultaneously with the background processing code also updating the spectral view's state.

There is a second issue;  your code is going to end up parallelizing the processing of all channels.   In general, unmitigated concurrency is a recipe for slow performance.   Also, you're going to cause an update on the main thread for each channel, regardless of whether or not the processing of that channel is completed.

---

The code needs to be restructured.   You really should split the model layer from the view layer.  The model layer could either be written to be thread safe *or*, during processing, you can grab a snapshot of the data to be displayed and toss that at the SpectralView.   Alternatively, your model layer could have an `isProcessing` flag that the SpectralView could key off of to know that it shouldn't be reading data.

This is relevant:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: Good summary of the issues. To the OP: A good rule of thumb: If you have an object that is a subclass of UIView, it shouldn't be touched from a background thread.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer and really helpful resource. Seems like I need to do some readings now!